# Ubuntu boots into virtual interface instead of the interface that has Internet

Tags: networking, interface

My Internet is on `enp1s0` with ip `192.168.1.14`.  I also have a virtual interface that I frequently ssh into on `enp1s0:0` with ip `192.168.1.113`.

When I reboot the computer, I have no Internet.  Using the GUI settings, under network it shows only my virtual interface with a checkmark on it.  If I go into its settings (for virtual interface) and remove the interface I immediately get Internet and it shows I'm connected to my usual wired connection.

How can I prevent this?  I want Ubuntu to use `enp1s0` and not `enp1s0:0` when I boot.